# How to ping a server/website with windows python?

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, server, ping

Like the title says, Im trying to ping a website (Like google.com) with python in windows. All I want the program to do is return True if the ping was received, or False if it wasn't. What is the absolutely most simple way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The simplest way is to use `os.system`. In Windows:

```
import os
def ping(address):
    return not os.system('ping %s -n 1' % (address,))
```

Windows' ping returns 0 on success and 1 on failure, so we need to `not` the result.

If you want to suppress ping's output, simply add `> NUL` to the command.

Comment: It's a logical operator that returns the (logical) opposite of the operand. Since ping would return 0 on success and 1 on failure, its logical value would be `False` on success and `True` on failure. You said you wanted the exact opposite of that, so I added `not` to the result.

Comment: Note that on windows 7 (and possibly other versions) ping returns 0 on any successes including "reply from x.y.z.254: Destination host unreachable"